# display xml response using jaxb

Tags: generics, jaxb

I have a responsewrapper class which is a generic class and  displays the response in xml form.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "XML")
public class ResponseWrapper<T> {
private T Respsonse;

ResponseWrapper(T Response){
    this.Respsonse=Response;
}

@XmlElement
public T getRepsonse() {
    return Respsonse;
}

public void setRepsonse(T repsonse) {
    Respsonse = repsonse;
}
```

}

I have a Employee class

```
public class Employee {
public String name;
public String address;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
```

}

Test class is as follows

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Employee e =new Employee();
    e.setName("guess");
    e.setAddress("xyz road and xyz country");
 ResponseWrapper<Employee> resp=new ResponseWrapper<Employee>(e);
 Employee e1=(Employee)resp.getRepsonse();
 System.out.print(resp);

}
```

}

When I run the test class I get the following response

ResponseWrapper@65690726 
I expected the response in the xml format :xml->employee->name->/name->.../employee.Can anyone please guide me where I am going wrong.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When trying to convert an `Employee` to XML, the following is how it is done with JAXB:

**Employee**

```
package forum9796799;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private String address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

**Test**

```
package forum9796799;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setName("guess");
        e.setAddress("xyz road and xyz country");

       JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
       Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
       marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
       marshaller.marshal(e, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<employee>
    <address>xyz road and xyz country</address>
    <name>guess</name>
</employee>
```

Comment: Hi Blaise thanks for the response.I know how to marhsal objects to xml but how would I do it for the generic class ResponseWrapper which can output any kind of objects.

Comment: @luckysing_noobster - Are you looking for something like the following:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it.I want to embed the Employee xml inside the ResponseWrapper xml.So later on If I need to add any kind of responsse type I can simply append it to ResponseWrapper.

Comment: I get the exception [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class Employee nor any of its super class is known to this context.]

Comment: I was able to do it!Thanks for all the help.